# How to get list of document from firestore in flutter based on field value

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

My firestore document contains names and other data too I just want to show names on the **ListView**
but ListView takes **itemCount** which takes the length of the document but my document contains other values like doc1(name), doc2(name), doc3(name), doc4(other value), doc5(other value), something like that
so the length of the document becomes 5 where I want the length of 3.

If I use the where clause it works fine, but then I can't use other data in my second **TabBarView**.

In other frameworks & languages, we can use the filter method to filter data from observable and display filtered data.

Hope someone understands my situation.

*Here is My Code:*

```
final nameList= FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userId)
        .collection('namesList')
        //.where('name', isNotEqualTo: '')   <------- works fine if I remove comment
        .snapshots();
```

Here is my Streambuilder:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: cropList,
              builder:
                  (BuildContext ctx, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.hasError) {
                  return Text('Something went wrong');
                }
                if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.data!.docs.isEmpty) {
                  return Text("Document does not exist");
                }

                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }

                return Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      Expanded(
                        child: ListView.builder(
                            itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length,                        
                            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) {
                              return Card(
                                elevation: 3,
                                child: ListTile(                                  
                                  leading: Text(snapshot.data?.docs[index]
                                          ['name']),
                                ),
                              );
                            }
                            ),
                      ),
                      Center(
                        child: Text('data'),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

hence I get an error: Bad state: field does not exist within the DocumentSnapshotPlatform

Comment: Hello Ahmed, could you please add a snapshot of your Firestore database?

Comment: your variable for the search inside your database is nameList, In your StreamBuilder the variable called is cropList. Please verify

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a typo:

I'm assuming the field is `name` and not `Name`

Try this:

```
final nameList= FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .doc(userId)
        .collection('namesList')
        .where('name', isNotEqualTo: '')
        .snapshots();
```

Comment: Not a type the field name is 'name' you can say typo in question but not in actual code.